# Cartoon in which a boy and girl travel with a robot

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I used to watch this cartoon when I was little, maybe around 2007, although I think it was older than that. I am not sure, but I think it was an anime. I do not remember it clearly but there was a boy and a girl who fought the bad guys. The boy and girl used to travel with the help of a giant robot or machine, they hopped on the legs of it. I think the robot looked like a cat (?) or some other animal. I've been searching on Google, but I can't find it with the little info I remember.

Comment: Hello! I've taken the liberty of editing your question for clarity, but there are still some thing you could us out with to make it easier to find an answer. Firstly, you say that that you watched this cartoon "when [you] were little", but since we don't know how old you are this doesn't really help to establish a timeframe. Do you know what year(s) you saw this cartoon, and whether it was in reruns or not?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Answer (score 3):

Could it be *Robotboy* you are talking about? The robot has ears that make his head look like a cat. There's 2 boys in it, and a girl and they both 'beat up bad guys'.

[image: Robotboy Volume 1 DVD cover showing the characters]

Comment: I've edited in the DVD cover of the first volume as it seems like it would be helpful for the OP to recognise this. Feel free to [edit] and revert my changes if you want.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be [Yatterman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yatterman) (or another humorous anime from Tatsunoko's [Time Bokan](https://timebokan.fandom.com/wiki/Time_Bokan_Wiki) series)?

Of course the two heroes had different robots, that were dogs, elephants, pelicans, pandas (I don't remember any cats), but the basic description corresponds: a boy and a girl who travel on the legs of a robot.

[image]
[image]

In that series, usually the bad guys were the true protagonists (and were usually very funny); they usually fought using small robots that came out from the mouth of the main robot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm distinctly getting a *Sym Bionic Titan* feel from this question. Posting a visual for the OP to reference:

[image]

I came to this conclusion from these details:

> .....around 2007, although I think it was older than that. I am not sure, but I think it was an anime.

This series focuses on a trio made up of "the alien princess Ilana, the strict, but rebellious soldier Lance, and the robot Octus; the three are able to combine to create the titular Sym-Bionic Titan." The titan could be seen as the robot, and though the years are a bit off the animation [not the art itself] used by creator Gennedy Tartakovsky was anime-inspired [as seen by the big eyes and hair], but not anime itself.